# Display a section of HTML codes when a certain data is present in the JSON data

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I want to display a section of HTML codes based on my data in a JSON file. For example, if the character * or - is present in the JSON data, then the section of HTML will be displayed. Otherwise, that section of HTML codes won't display.

I have been trying to do a simple if else but unable to find any answers online. What I'm trying to do is

```
if (- or * is true) {
    display the html 
}
else {
    do nothing
}
```

Currently, the JSON data are being stored in an array.
`const transcriptData = get(certificate, "transcript", []);`

This is one of the objects in my JSON data looks like when I do a `console.log(transcriptData);`

One of the object:

```
courseCode: "GST102"
creditUnits: "5.0"
gradePoint: 4.5
name: "Western Digital Painting"
result: "-"
semester: "2"
year: "2017"
```

So in the sample data above, there is a "-" character. Hence the section of the HTML code that I want will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/vqQqGW). I hope it can help you

```js
// functional Component to show only the items where result === '-' or '*'
const ListItem = ({item}) => {
  if (item.result === '-' || item.result === '*'){
    return (
    <li key={item.courseCode}>
        <p><label>Name:</label>{item.name}</p>
        <p><label>Year/Semester:</label>{item.year}/{item.semester}</p>
      </li>)
  }
  return null
}

// Main Component
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    // your data
    this.state = [
      {
        courseCode: "GST102",
        creditUnits: "5.0",
        gradePoint: 4.5,
        name: "Western Digital Painting",
        result: "-",
        semester: "2",
        year: "2017",
      },
      {
        courseCode: "GST103",
        creditUnits: "4.0",
        gradePoint: 4.5,
        name: "Northern Digital Communication",
        result: "",
        semester: "2",
        year: "2016",
      },
      {
        courseCode: "GST104",
        creditUnits: "6.0",
        gradePoint: 6.5,
        name: "Western Digital Programming",
        result: "-",
        semester: "1",
        year: "2018",
      },
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.map(item => (<ListItem item={item} />))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <List />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```